# Spring AOP with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, aop

Is it safe to use spring AOP with async thread processing?

Let me make it a bit clear with a code sample:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = within(com..*)", returning = "result")
public void sampleWithNewThread(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
         dbConnection.write(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
         dbConnection.write(result);
    });
}
```

Is it safe to "touch" the joinPoint and result objects in the new Thread? are those thread-safe?

I'm pretty sure its ok but I cannot find a proof reference for it.

Comment: For getting the name, yeah, that's fine. But you're also operating on `result`. That's on you to make it thread safe/immutable.

Comment: thanks :), I'm more concern about the joinPoint object. Is it safe to do more operations on it? besides the getName()..

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [`JoinPoint`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) and of the types that you can retrieve from it (eg. `Signature`) don't explicitly state that they are thread safe. However, they don't provide any way to mutate them, ie. they only expose getter methods.

You can take this to mean that they are immutable, but you don't need to. Just retrieve the value within the thread that invokes the `@AfterReturning` annotated method and pass those values to the other thread.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = within(com..*)", returning = "result")
public void sampleWithNewThread(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    final String signatureName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    executorService.submit(() -> {
         dbConnection.write(signatureName);
         dbConnection.write(result);
    });
}
```